# How to use gdb to debug a codebase with recursive makefiles

Tags: c++, makefile, gdb, gnu-make

I was given a huge code composed of c++ and QT modules. To compile, I need to run ./configure and then make.

./configure generates several makefiles in directories and subdirectories and running make recursively runs make in directories.

Now I want to change a very small portion of the code in test.h.
The executable is in a different folder.

Here is the problem;

```
# gdb foo
Reading symbols from /xx/yy/zz/foo

(gdb) break ../qq/zz/test.h:53
No source file named ../qq/zz/test.h
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])
```

I have tried absolute path also , but didn't work either.

Then I did this:

```
(gdb) add-symbol-file  ../qq/zz/someObjFile.o
The address where ../qq/zz/someObjFile.o has been loaded is missing
```

Then I tried this:

```
(gdb) symbol-file ../qq/zz/someObjFile.o
Load new symbol table from "../qq/zz/someObjFile.o"? (y or n) y
Reading symbols from  "../qq/zz/someObjFile.o" ...done
(gdb) break test.h:53
Cannot access memory at address 0x20
```

I have seen some threads answering " Cannot access memory at address" by find the actual memory address, but I think this is not what I need. and I am missing something way simpler.

If it helps:

I'm using GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1)  and someObjFile.o is the object file generated by makefile in the folder that test.h exists (test.h is included in someObjFile.cpp  file)

Any hints is appreciated.

Comment: It is most likely that you are compiling without symbols (-g option) or that you're stripping them during the make process (??). BTW, I don't having recursive Makefiles have anything to do with your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I double checked makefiles to make sure -g is there, and they all have -g flag. And by recursive makefiles I meant there are multiple makefiles each responsible for compiling a piece of code (as you pointed out it has nothing to do with recursion, but just emphasizing on multiple makefiles).  Could you elaborate on "you're stripping them during the make process".

Comment: There's a command [strip](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strip) that removes symbol symbol information.

Comment: What kind of breakpointable object includes test.h:53? Can you set a breakpoint using the object's name?

Comment: Thanks, I do not know how it appears in the makefiles. So I'm going to check the makefiles to see whether they do stripping. However, I guess my main problem is that I have separate makefiles that each compiles a separate portion of the code and I can not mix the resulting debugging info.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, would you elaborate on "breakpointable object"? test.h:53 is a simple code line (say an assignment) and I have tried several lines (say test.h:123 , test.h:326), ... but none works.

Comment: Sorry, I meant, test.h:53 presumably lies inside a function or method. Can you set a breakpoint on that function or method or `list` that function or method? I want to see how much debugging info your `gdb` session has access to at this point.

Comment: Thanks guys for helping me. I did (gdb) list func (assume func is the method that line 53 lies in) result is :"Function "func" not defined." To me, the problem looks like this: My debugging info are spread in several folders (each generated by a separate makefile) and I can not merge all debugging info !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDB does not load symbols from `.so` files until you run the program. Also, the files may be referred to by file name, without paths.

Try

```
b main
r
...
...
# GDB stops
b test.h:57
```

Also, sometimes on large projects GDB gets confused about line numbers. Try setting breakpoints on a function.

Comment: If that works, the next time you can just answer "y" to "Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load?" - and you should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

```
(gdb) break ../qq/zz/test.h:53
No source file named ../qq/zz/test.h
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])
```

This *usually* means that the code in question was built into a shared library, and you have *not* loaded that shared library *yet*.

You should either answer `yes` to the question GDB is asking, or just run the application once (which will make GDB load and retain debugging symbols for all libraries used in that run), and *then* set a breakpoing for the second run.

> Then I did this:

Furious activity is not a substitute for understanding. Since you lack understanding, it's unlikely that typing various "random" commands into GDB will help you.

Update:

> again the same error as "No source file named..."

Well, it's also possible that code in `someObjFile.o` is not in fact ever loaded into your process. One easy way to confirm this is to put `assert(0)` in line 53 of `test.h`. If your program still runs, then (assuming you do not use `-DNDEBUG` when building) you can be sure that line 53 was in fact never executed.

Comment: "Since you lack understanding" is totally true! I googled to see how can I merge debugging info, but as you can see I got more confused ! Based on your answer, I answered yes and (gdb) run , then no breakpoints were applied. Next I ran (gdb) start , then set the breakpoint still having the same problem. Would you explain what do you mean by "run the application once and then set a breakpoing for the second run." I ran the program (by running the executable), then tried to set breakpoint, again the same error as "No source file named..."

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I tried that (actually with a cout!) and made sure that execution reaches there.

Comment: thanks a lot, when I saw Arkadiy's answer then I understood what you were referring to by saying "run the application once and then set a breakpoint". You exactly meant what  Arkadiy said.

Comment: So, Even though setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH in a sub-shell of GDB may resolve the problem, but is not a correct way to solve the issue.